# How to break down a full name into parts and insert them into multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that allows me to select [select form] a student's name (full name).

I want to break down the full name into parts (first name, last name) and insert them into a form (hidden), then submit it via ajax to the database.

**(code snippet for the html form, this is part of a modal triggered by a button)**

```html
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="first_name" required>
                          </div>

                          <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="last_name" required>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Account User</label>
                            <select type="select" id="select-student" class="form-control select2 select-student" name="student" required>
                              <option value="" selected disabled>Select Student</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

**(code for the select form, I'm using select2 for the search bar)**

```js
function getAllStudents() {
    $.ajax({
            url: "students",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
              var html = '<option value="" selected disabled>Select Student</option>';
              $.each(data, function(x,y) {
                  html += '<option value="'+y.id+'">'+y.first_name+ " "+y.middle_initial+" "+y.last_name+'</option>';
              });
              $('#select-student').html(html);
            }
          });
  }
```

**(javascript to trigger the modal, together with triggering the select list)**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn-add-account', function() {
      $('#add-account-modal').modal('show');
      getAllStudents();
    });
```

**(code for sending the information to the database)**

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#form-add-account', function() {
       $.ajax({
            url: "register",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              if (data.success === true) {
                alert("Account Successfully Added!");
                location.reload();
              }
              else {
                alert("Something went wrong");
              }
            }
          });
            return false;
    });
```

Additional information, if it would help: The select list (select-student) gets the students list from the database, and there are columns for first_name, middle_initial, and last_name there.

Thank you!

EDIT: Sample Ajax return would be the following -

select-student will return a list of student names:

Marcus L. Pearson (format: first_name + middle_initial + last_name)
Michael K. Jackson

upon selecting (in this case, I'll select Michael K. Jackson), I want it then to be split into diff. parts in multiple forms.

#first_name = Michael

#middle_initial = K.

#last_name = Jackson

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Whats the problem? ... Although, nice explanation of the environment. I would just edit to be more specific about where you exactly need help.

Comment: Please provide some sample data that would be returned via AJAX call.

Comment: Edited, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you need is this:

```
function splitName(str) {
  var r = str.split(" ");
  return {
    first_name: r[0],
    middle_initial: r[1],
    last_name: r[2]
  };
}

$('#select-student').change(function() {
  var y = splitName($("option:selected", this).text().trim());
  $("input[type='hidden'][name='first_name']").val(y.first_name);
  $("input[type='hidden'][name='last_name']").val(y.last_name);
});
```

You may consider adding unique IDs or unique classes in case there are other form elements with these same attributes.

Putting it all together, it would look like this:

```js
$(function() {

  function splitName(str) {
    var r = str.split(" ");
    return {
      "first_name": r[0],
      "middle_initial": r[1],
      "last_name": r[2]
    };
  }

  function getAllStudents() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "students",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#select-student').html("");
        $("<option>").val("").prop({
          selected: true,
          disabled: true
        }).appendTo($('#select-student'));
        $.each(data, function(x, y) {
          $("<option>").val(y.id).html(y.first_name + " " + y.middle_initial + " " + y.last_name).appendTo($('#select-student'));
        });
      }
    });
  }

  $('#select-student').change(function() {
    var y = splitName($("option:selected", this).text().trim());
    $("input[type='hidden'][name='first_name']").val(y.first_name);
    $("input[type='hidden'][name='last_name']").val(y.last_name);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#btn-add-account', function() {
    $('#add-account-modal').modal('show');
    getAllStudents();
  });

  $(document).on('submit', '#form-add-account', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "register",
      type: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.success === true) {
          alert("Account Successfully Added!");
          location.reload();
        } else {
          alert("Something went wrong");
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="first_name" required>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="last_name" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Account User</label>
  <select type="select" id="select-student" class="form-control select2 select-student" name="student" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Student</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Unable to test since there was no example data and cannot perform AJAX in Snippet.

Comment: EDIT: Question, what if the First_Name has two names? e.g. Michael Angelo (first_name) Diaz (Last_name). ?

Comment: EDIT 2: I managed to make a fix by making the str.split look for double spaces ("  "), instead of single spaces when splitting, as first names (with double names) usually have single space on them, so I put double spaces in between y.first_name and the rest of the names.

Thank you!